# combine Not In and like function in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-like, in-operator

I want to know is there there a way to merge `not in()` function with `like` or wildcard `*` in MySQL? Like in the following query:

```
select sl_tags from tablname
    where `sl_tags` not in ('%Soccer%','%Football%','%Hockey%','%shinny%','%Basketball%','%Volleyball%','%Cricket%')
```

the above query does not work.

I know this works

```
select sl_tags from tablname where `sl_tags` Not like '%Soccer%' and `sl_tags` Not like '%Football%'
```

I saw previous questions and answers on stack which asked, and did not find any relevant answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no such operator.

But you can do this in slightly different manner using [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT sl_tags
  FROM tablname
  WHERE sl_tags NOT REGEXP 'Soccer|Football|Hockey|shinny|Basketball';
```

Be aware that for some characters (like dot `.`) have special meaning and need to be [escaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) to be used literally.

Comment: Thanks @Barmaley.exe , i find something like this.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use `not like`:

```
select sl_tags
from tablname
where sl_tags Not like '%Soccer%', and
      sl_tags Not like '%Football%' and
      sl_tags Not like '%Hockey%', and
      sl_tags Not like '%shinny%' and
      sl_tags Not like '%Basketball%' and
      sl_tags Not like '%Volleyball%' and
      sl_tags Not like '%Cricket%';
```

You don't provide information, but the column names suggest that you are storing lists of tags in the `sl_tags` column.  This is not the best approach.  You should have a separate table containing one tag per row in your original data.  The query on the junction table would then be simpler.

Comment: Gordon, I mentioned this query in question and worked well but my question i.e. i want to another way to get same result. Some other operators are as : Not LIKE ANY (ARRAY['%xyz%','%abc%'])